# Popup border is ugly, how can I make it look nice?

Tags: popup-menu

This is the default border, it looks ugly

[image: default border]

This is the FZF preview window. It looks pretty nice. How can I make Vim's popups look rounded like FZF's window?

[image: fzf border]

---

Update: thanks @ralf ! it works !

I replace it with...

Rounded:

```
['─', '│', '─', '│', '╭', '╮', '╯', '╰'],
```

Sharp:

```
['─', '│', '─', '│', '┌', '┐', '┘', '└'],
```

[image: fzf style]

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Nice question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The border depends on `'encoding'` and `'ambiwidth'`. From the docs:

> By default a double line is used all around when 'encoding' is "utf-8" and
>   'ambiwidth' is "single", otherwise ASCII characters are used.

In your case ASCII characters are used.

If you programmed the popup yourself, see `:h popup` and search for `borderchars`.

BTW: I don't think that fzf is using Vim popup.

Comment: IIRC `fzf` spins up a terminal (in or out of vim) when invoked via its vim plugin.

Comment: To be precise, `fzf` uses a terminal, except in Terminal Vim with the default layout (`:h fzf-inside-terminal-buffer`).